# How do I edit contacts in Android 4.4?

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat

On my Android 2.3 phone I've exported my contacts and imported them on my new Android 4.4 phone, a Motorola G. Unfortunately, I found no way to edit the contact. When I open the "phone" application from the main screen, I click "All contacts" (translated) to get the list of all contacts. But as soon as I click on one item, it dials. Click-and-hold does nothing - no context menu occurs. How to edit the contacts (name, phone number)?

Comment: Wasn't able to answer, but for those who don't see 3 dots on top-right, just tap the 3rd (rightmost) button on your mobile (`back | home | options`), it'll show up a menu containing `Edit`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the phone/dialer app to edit contacts: use the main **People** app (it's called **Contacts** on some non-Nexus phones). From that app, when you click the contact you want, it displays that contact, and you can click the pencil icon on the *action bar* (at the top) to edit the contact. (The icon might look different on your phone, because most manufacturers replace the People app with their own variant.)

Comment: Yuck! Doesn't the dialer app invoke the contacts/people app on a Nexus, like on most decent phones? =:-0 <rant>That reminds me of those times on stock-HTC-Android-2.1, where the first thing I replaced was the dialer (exactly because of this). Thought those times were long gone, as that's everything but intuitive or user-friendly. Don't want to know how many people got wakend during night-sleep because of that... </rant>

Comment: you dont need to do use the `People` app - as per some of the answers below when viewing a Contact click on the little person icon on the right hand side...that then appears to take you to the people app where you can edit by clicking the 3 dots in the upper top right

Comment: @wal Since you're familiar with the Moto G's interface in particular, you should add your own answer.

Comment: @DanHulme suggest updating your answer to reflect the fact you dont need to use the People app always

Comment: @wal I can't write that description, because I don't have a Moto G and don't know the interface. That's why I say you should write up an answer yourself, instead of burying the information in the comments of a different answer.

Comment: @DanHulme Perhaps you can state what phone your answer pertains to? I see neither the pencil icon nor any 'action bar at the top' so your answer was not helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to click the **image**, not the remainder of the item, to be able to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

For Moto G and (possibly many other android devices) you *can* do this directly from the phone app:

Tap the person icon followed by the three dots in the top right (See circled icons below)

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

in KitKat 4.4.2, To view contact details just click the image of a certain person on your **Contact App** (not the dialer) but if you want to edit click on the name. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this on my Nexus 4 w/4.4.2 and the above answer is partially right. Open your contacts and tap on the picture to open up the contact. Now tap the silhouette of the person next to the star. Now you can tap the 3 dots in the upper right corner and that opens up the editor. Finish the edit and tap done in the upper left.

Comment: It's no use referring to "the above answer" on this site. Answers can be displayed in different orders, so you should [edit] your answer to specify which one you mean. Also, note that the Motorola G has a different contacts app to the Nexus 4, so your answer might not be applicable to the questioner.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the dial (phone icon). Find the person you intend to text. Select the 3 dot icon on the far right (at the bottom). Select "all contacts". Boom! Just scroll to the contact and select. I hope this gets ironed out as well.

Comment: this is inaccurate. I figured it out earlier yesterday. I got my wires crossed. I will figure it out and repost.

Comment: got it!!! Same procedure as above. I was correct. When you select the recipient for the text, look to the far right icon. Select that, and text away.

Comment: disregard all that nonsense. just tap on the picture of the person you intend to text. foot in mouth.

Comment: tapping on the right direct dials. sorry. inquisitive loudmouth dumbass.

Comment: chris, please clean up your comments. Don't add facts as comments, instead [edit] your answer and integrate them. Currently it's nothing but confusing: yes, no, inaccurate, no, nonsense, tap elsewhere... What's supposed to be your answer here?